# Create plot with only x axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, bubble-chart

I want to create a bubble plot without the y axis, meaning the x axis represents a range between certain values and the size of the bubbles corresponds to a "number" variable.

Since `geom_point()` requires a y variable, I created a `new` column with only zero values and assigned it to the y axis.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=range, y=new, size = numberPoints)) +
    geom_point(alpha=0.5, shape=19) +
    scale_size(range = c(.1, 24)) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = NULL)
```

However, it gave the following result (the y axis is too large):

[image]

I only wanted the bubbles above the x axis (without too much space), but I can't find a way to do it.

Comment: Can you make your post [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and provide `dput(df)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `coord_fixed` to "reduce" your axis

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4), size = c(1,1,4,8)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=x, y=1, size = size)) +
  geom_point(alpha=0.5, shape=19) +
  scale_size(range = c(.1, 24)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = NULL)+
  coord_fixed(6)
```

[image]